# php get value of submit button when value is a variable

Tags: php, variables, button, submit

I tried to search but was unable to find an answer for this question.

I am trying to get the value of the button in my submit button that is a variable.

CODE is as follows

```
$penrequest = "select * from request where status='pending';";
$penreg = mysql_query($penrequest);
echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($peneg))
{
 echo "<input type='submit' name='answer' value='$appdeny'>";
}

if (isset($_POST['answer']))
{
   echo $appdeny;
}
```

Ok the code works...if you hit the button its caught by the if statement like its supposedt o be. the variable $appdeny is a messageID number filled from a mysql database which can change. When the user clicks a button i want to print the messageID of the number displayed as the value of the answer button.

Comment: pls show us the code for button

Comment: Your first line has an extra ; between the ' and the ".  Your question is confusing me.  I'm not even sure what you're really asking.  Your question contains no question marks.

Comment: `mysql_*` are deprecated so avoid using them .. use `mysqli_` or `PDO`

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='answer' value='$appdeny'>";
```

to:

```
echo "<input type='submit' name='answer' value='" . $row['appdeny'] . "'>";
```

Change:

```
echo $appdeny;
```

to:

```
echo $_POST['answer'];
```

You also need to do:

```
echo "</form>";
```

after the `while` loop.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfect and achieved the goal i was going for.